# Singly Linked List using Arrays: It's crashing on run-time

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

Whats wrong with this code?
I am writing this code to implement singly linked list using arrays but its not working. Im using code::blocks and its crashing on run time. Please help.
I must have missed out on something when it was taught in the class. xD

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(int n)
    {
        data=n;
        next=NULL;
    }
    friend class List;
};
class List
{
    Node *listptr;
public:
void create();
void display();
};
void List::create()
{
    Node *temp;
    int n, num;
    cout << "Enter number of nodes:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "/nEnter the data" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        Node *new_node=new Node(num);
        if(listptr==NULL)
            listptr=temp=new_node;
        else
        {
            temp->next=new_node;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}
void List::display()
{
    Node *temp=listptr;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << "->";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
 main()
{
    List l1;
    l1.create();
    l1.display();
}
```

Comment: I recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to use a debugger to catch crashes and location where they happen.

Comment: Looking at the code I'm confused if this is supposed to be C or C++ too.

Comment: `Node *temp;` is never initialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay I'll learn it! thanks a ton! :)

Comment: You haven't used any array. If you're supposed to do that, you probably should.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listptr` not initialized, you can initialize in `constructor`.

```
  List() {
      listptr = 0;
   }
```

Class `List` should be

```
class List
{
        Node *listptr;
        public:
        List() {
        listptr = 0;
        }
        void create();
        void display();
};
```

Comment: OMG you are a life saver!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try following piece of code -

**First Creating Node**

```
class ListElement
{
    int data;
    ListElement* next;

public:
    void set_element(int item) { data = item; }
    int get_value() { return data; }
    friend class List;
};
```

**Another class for further operation**

```
class List
{
    ListElement *Start, *Tail, *New;
public:
    List() { Start = Tail = New = NULL; }  // initialise all pointer value to NULL

    void add_element(int element) {

        // Create a new Node
        New = new ListElement;
        New->set_element(element);
        New->next = NULL;

        // adding value or linkig each node to each other
        (Start == NULL) ? Start = New : Tail->next = New;
        Tail = New;

    }

    // print the whole linked list
    void print()
    {
        ListElement* Current = Start;

        while (Current != NULL)
        {
            cout << Current->get_value() << endl;
            Current = Current->next;
        }
    }

};
```

**Main Function**

```
int main()
{
    List L;
    int num_of_element, element;
    cin >> num_of_element;

    for (int i(0); i < num_of_element; i++) {
        cin >> element;
        L.add_element(element);
    }
    L.print();

}
```

Hope it'll work.